# Why can I not access my scope attributes when using $new?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a context menu directive with some specific characteristics (that are not directly relevant to this question). I've attempted to implement this as an "attachment" directive that attaches the scope of the element it's set on, to a pre-made "menu" element. Since I was unable to find any canonical documentation on this topic, I've based my implementation on some digging around with the Chrome Developer Tools.

I have made a simplified testcase that shows my implementation (and the problem) here: http://plnkr.co/edit/URafJe0OcRsMsmaEdmDi?p=preview

It effectively uses `$new` on the element's scope to create a new inheriting child scope, and then attempts to attach that scope to the 'menu' element (referenced by ID), by setting its `$scope` data property, and setting the `ng-scope` class.

The problem I am encountering, is that the menu element *still* does not seem to be able to access the attached scope. Any expression relating to that scope, comes up empty (again, see the Plunker above). The `$scope` data property is correctly set to the newly created inheriting child scope, and that scope is correctly inheriting so that the parent scope values *should* be accessible. I have also verified that it is interpreting any bindings *at all* by adding a simple "1 + 1" expression - this works fine.

Why can I not access the scope that is supposedly attached to the element, and/or what is the correct way to manually attach a scope to an element in a directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fork of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/V0dbM4NFcxdT8YEXWs4l?p=preview

I dont know how to do what you want without using $compile. I did something like this in the plunkr:

```
menu_element = $compile(menu_element)(child_scope);
```

Comment: Thanks; this answer made me realize that I was going about this wrong, and that I should be instantiating templates rather than moving around a pre-existing element :)